# How to call a factory from a factory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I can't find a clear answer to this so apologies in advance if there is.

(This plunker)http://plnkr.co/edit/EmEQt9KlApc9I1AIraBZ?p=catalogue shows the current state of my code. There is a controller which returns a http query:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
.module('marketsApp')
.controller('marketLocationController', marketLocationController);

marketLocationController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams',    'marketLocationService'];

function marketLocationController($scope, $routeParams, marketLocationService) {
    $scope.center = {};
    $scope.markers = {};

    // console.log(geo.coords);

    activate ();

    function activate () {
        getMarketLocations();
    }

    function getMarketLocations() {
        var marketList = marketLocationService.getMarkets();
        $scope.marketList = marketList;
        // insert list template here
    }
}

})();
```

The query takes three parameters, a location from this factory:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
.module('marketsApp')
.factory('BrowserLocation', BrowserLocation);

BrowserLocation.$inject = ['$q'];

function BrowserLocation() {

    return {
        getLocation: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    deferred.resolve(position);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}
})();
```

and two parameters from this factory, which will be either a query or accessed from local storage eventually:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
.module('marketsApp')
.factory('userDefaultsService', userDefaultsService);

userDefaultsService.$inject = ['$q'];

function userDefaultsService($q) {

    return {
      getDefaults: function () {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var userDefaults = {
              dist: 25,
              limit: 100
          };
        return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}

})();
```

and the query is constructed in this factory:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
.module('marketsApp')
.factory('marketLocationService', marketLocationService);

marketLocationService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'BrowserLocation', 'userDefaultsService'];

function marketLocationService($http, $q, BrowserLocation, userDefaultsService) {

var apiUrl = "/api/markets/bylocation";

    return {
        getMarkets: getMarkets
    };

    function getMarkets () {

        // var self = this;
        var apiParams = {
            point: null,
            dist: null,
            limit: null
        };

        var thisLocation = null;
        var thisDefault = null;

        thisLocation = function (location) {
            BrowserLocation.getLocation()
        };

        thisDefault = function (defaults)   {
            userDefaultsService.getDefaults();
        };

        // extract the params here
        // (this is how it should work)
        // lat = thisLocation.coords.latitude;
        // lon = thisLocation.coords.longitude;
        // apiParams.point = lat + "," lon;
        // apiParams.dist = thisDefault.dist;
        // apiParams.limit = thisDefault.limit;

        $http({
            url: apiUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                point: point,
                dist: dist,
                limit: limit
            }
        });
    }
}

})();
```

I can't get BrowserLocation and userDefaultsService to return their objects so that I can pass them into apiParams. I know I have to probably use $q or .then to make sure both resolve but at the moment I don't seem to have the correct method of querying the factories, so my question is how do I query a factory from another factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$q.all` to wait for multiple promises to resolve. In `marketLocationService` wait for both `BrowserLocation.getLocation` and `userDefaultsService.getDefaults`. Then when they're resolved execute the `$http` request:

```
$q.all([BrowserLocation.getLocation(), userDefaultsService.getDefaults()]).then(function(values) {
// here values[0] is response from getLocation
// values[1] is response from getDefaults
          $http({
            url: apiUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                point: point,
                dist: dist,
                limit: limit
            }
        });
        });
```

You also need to to resolve `userDefaultsService.getDefaults` assuming it should be async:

```
return {
      getDefaults: function () {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var userDefaults = {
              dist: 25,
              limit: 100
          };
          $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve(userDefaults);
          })
        return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
```

See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCMEkMgHV27IrkQXcCop?p=preview) plunker